# How do I write template template parameters correctly?

Tags: c++, templates, collections, adapter

I'm trying to make an adapter for any C++ collections using templates.

I need to use template template parameters so I could use adapter like:

```
CollectionAdapter<std::vector<int>> a;
```

And not like:

```
CollectionAdapter<std::vector<int>,int> a;
```

Which requires two template parameters at once.

I wrote this class:

```
template <
    template <class U> class T
>
class CollectionAdapter {

public:
    typedef T<U> ThisCol;
    typedef void iterator;

    CollectionAdapter() {}

    bool add(ThisCol& c,const U& i);
    bool remove(ThisCol& c,const U& i);
    U& getByIndex(int i);
    ThisCol instantiate();
    iterator getIterator(ThisCol& c);

};
```

However, visual studio compiler throws me this error:

```
error C2065: 'U' : undeclared identifier
```

For this line:

```
typedef T<U> ThisCol;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your title is bad, please consider improving it.

Comment: I fail to see why you need template template parameters here. Can't you just have a single parameter for the full container type?

Comment: Well, I need to know what type and to add from add or remove methods. If you have a better solution, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need template template parameters. You can simplify your code:

```
template <class T>
class CollectionAdapter 
{

public:
    typedef T ThisCol;
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;

    //typedef void iterator; // what?? did you mean void*?
    typedef void* void_iterator; // but not sure what the use of this is.

    // you might need the container's iterator types too
    typedef typename T::iterator iterator
    typedef typename T::const_iterator const_iterator


    CollectionAdapter() {}

    bool add(T& c,const value_type& i);
    bool remove(T& c,const value_type& i);
    value_type& getByIndex(int i);
    const value_type& getByIndex(int i) const;
    ThisCol instantiate();
    iterator getIterator(T& c);

};
```

Comment: What's a value type? This should be deduced in template specializations?

Comment: @VanillaFace That is a type defined in all standard library container class templates. It is the type of the things stored in the container.